# preg_replace degree and phi symobols

Tags: php, regex

I've tried in many ways to replace ONLY degree and (greek)Phi symbols. I've googled and did everything the articles said to do, it's driving me crazy. I can't use  `htmlentities()` because I don't want to encode the html tags... just those two characters, I do this... it doesn't return an error, just replaces the entire string with nothing

```
preg_replace(array('/( )+/', '/\x{00B0}/u', '/\x{03A6}/u', '/\x{03D5}/u'), array(' ','&deg;','&Phi;','&Phi;'), $str);
```

By The Way, the first replace just gets rid of extra white space and that works fantastic, but when I add in the other three (degree, capital Phi and lowercase Phi), the entire string gets replaced with white space.

Comment: Could you add some input ? Maybe also an [online demo](https://eval.in) ?

Comment: You might get better luck in just using str_replace

Comment: I'll give you an online demo and I'll try str_replace too, doing that now

Comment: We figured out it's a problem with the input itself. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Thank you guys for taking the time to reply, I've up voted both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your code is working as expected

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/qDDsY3)

## Example

**Code**

```
<?php

$string = 'hi ϕllip       it is 900°';

$output = preg_replace(array('/( )+/', '/\x{00B0}/u', '/\x{03A6}/u', '/\x{03D5}/u'), array(' ','&deg;','&Phi;','&Phi;'), $string );


    echo "this is the output:"  . $output;
```

**Output**

```
this is the output:hi &Phi;llip it is 900&deg;
```

Comment: We figured out that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. It's basically for a data entry thing, but half of the files are encoded in something weird from whatever time era. I'm just having the people manually replace the symbol with the entity. Thank you for taking the time to answer :)